# Can I combine USING and ON in a single join?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5. I'd like to have the column-merging functionality of `USING` in a query where not all of the columns that I'm using for the join are named the same. For example:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM table_a a
 INNER JOIN table_b b USING(shared_id) AND a.foo = b.bar
```

The above code doesn't work. Is there something I can write to get this effect? Or do I need to do `ON a.shared_id = b.shared_id AND a.foo = b.bar`?

Comment: Try changing the `AND` to a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **CAN'T** use both

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html

> The join condition is specified in the ON or USING clause, or implicitly by the word NATURAL. The join condition determines which rows from the two source tables are considered to "match", as explained in detail below.

Focus on the or part. `ON` **or** `USING`